# Why can't 12.04 installer see one of my hard drives

Tags: 12.04, installation, hard-drive, ubiquity

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit from a USB pen drive. I have two drives, a WD Caviar Black and a Samsung SPC250.

At the "installation type" stage, it only sees my Samsung and the USB pen drive, not the WD.

- I checked the drive with `gparted` and everything seems fine.
- I tried the alternate installer but that doesn't work either
- I tried changing from IDE to AHCI in the BIOS and back

What can I do now?

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/52127870/Screenshot%20from%202012-06-10%2008%3A01%3A50.png]

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/52127870/Screenshot%20from%202012-06-10%2008%3A03%3A38.png]

1st picture, g.parted shows `WD` disk as `sda`. But `ubiquity` can't see.Only my second drive as `sdb`.Even i reserved space as `ext4` for installation.
2nd picture,you can see 1tb `sda` disk. But it unable to mount.

I want to install ubuntu to `sda` disk.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please clarify what you mean when you say only your Samsung and your USB (install) drive are available at the `Installation Type` stage?

Have you selected `Something Else` in the first  `Installation Type` window and then pressed the <kbd>Continue</kbd> button to display the window which allows you to do your own partitioning as shown in the example screenshot below?

If you've reached the partitioning window (below) have you scrolled the list and it only has entries for two drives? But if you start `gparted` after booting your install USB and choosing `Try Ubuntu`, then all three drives are shown?

[image: screenshot of Install Type roll-your-own partitions window showing 3 drives]